# Mongoose: validation error path `name` is required

Tags: node.js

Here is my HTML with the form piece.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSave()" *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Organization Name">
```

Here is the code for onSave() from my component.ts file.

```
onSave() {
  if (this.form.invalid) {
    return;
  }
  this.isLoading = true;
  if (this.mode === "create") {
    this.objsService.add(
      this.form.value.name
    );
  } else {
    this.objsService.update(
      this.id,
      this.form.value.name
    );
  }
  this.form.reset();
}
```

Here is the add() function from my service.

```
/* #region  Create of CRUD */
add(name: string) {
  const objData = new FormData();
  objData.append("name", name);
  this.http
    .post<{ message: string; obj: Organization }>(
      'http://localhost:3000/api/organizations',
      objData
    )
    .subscribe(responseData => {
      this.router.navigate(["/organizations"]);
    });
}
/* #endregion */
```

And lastly here is my .post to the router in mp api.

```
/* #region  Create of CRUD */
router.post('', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('req.body.name: ' + req.body.name);
  const obj = new objModel({
    name: req.body.name
  });
  obj.save().then(createdObj => {
    res.status(201).json({
      message: capitalize(plural) + ' added successfully',
      obj: {
        ...createdObj,
        id: createdObj._id
      }
    });
  });
});
/* #endregion */
```

As you can see in my api I''m running "console.log('req.body.name: ' + req.body.name);", it's output is "req.body.name: undefined".  How could this be?  What am I missing?

In my service I ended up add the following line.

```
add(name: string) {
  const objData = new FormData();
  objData.append('name', name);
  console.log(name);
  console.log(objData);
```

Here's what showed up in the console.

```
dfgasdfg

FormData {}
  __proto__: FormData
    append: ƒ append()
    ...
    values: ƒ values()
      arguments: (...)
      ...
      name: "values"
        __proto__: ƒ ()
        ...
        name: ""
```

name: "" should be name: "dfgasdfg".  Is the .append syntax incorrect?

Here's my server.js file.  I did include body-parser.  Did I implement it improperly?

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const postsRoutes = require("./routes/posts");
const organizationsRoutes = require("./routes/organizations");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i think you missing body-parser middleware in node api that's why you getting undefined in req.

Answer (score 0):

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

please try to use above express middleware in `server.js` root file, to get data in `req.body` object.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I have body-parser in my code.  See above, I updated my post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm an idiot.  I needed to use the following.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

I was using:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

Thanks for the direction!!!!

P.S.

Ok, I take it back.  It wasn't a permanent fix.  I am running express 6.9.0, doesn't express 4.16+ have it's own parser?  I changed my code to now have this:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

In my route for the API it looks like it's still not populating req.body.name with the value from the form.

Using this:

```
console.log('req.body.name: ' + req.body.name);
```

I get this:

```
req.body.name: undefined
```